# Can't execute script from command line

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have PL/pgSQL function definitions that need to be run from the file scripts in the process of creating a new data. However I get errors while using psql.exe with the functions in the file, yet running it in the SQL editor from within pgAdminIII is completely fine. What could the problem be ? Is there any other simple solution of running the PL/pgSQL scripts ?

This is the error message:

> psql:./../Generic_SQL/db-create-functions-generic.sql:17: ERROR: 
>   syntax error a t or near "ï»¿CREATE" LINE 1: ï»¿CREATE OR REPLACE
>   FUNCTION pk_get(tabname character varyi...

And the command line is:

```
C:\"Program Files"\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql -d OR -U postgres -f ".\..\Generic_SQL\db-create-lic-tables.sql"
```

And the actual file contents is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pk_get(tabname character varying)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    ThePK integer;
BEGIN

    --XStr:=TabName || HospUnitID; 
    --EXECUTE 'SELECT nextval(''' ||TabName || HospUnitID|| '''::regclass)' INTO ThePK; -- '' for the key name needed, so to escape needs dbl + general (so triple)
    --ThePK:=HospUnitID*100000 + ThePK+1;
    EXECUTE 'SELECT nextval(''' ||TabName || '_seq''::regclass)' INTO ThePK; -- '' for the key name needed, so to escape needs dbl + general (so triple)

    RETURN ThePK;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;    -- This is the line 17 that's apparently problematic
ALTER FUNCTION pk_get(character varying)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: try opening script in notepad and then File->Save As->Unicode instead of ANSI

Comment: I did that, but I saved it to ANSI and it worked. Thanks

Comment: You can also save as UTF8 without BOM. Specially if you need non-ansi characters.